# Residual standard error vs Standard error of residual

Tags: regression, terminology, standard-error

In linear regression,

- Residual standard error = estimate of the standard deviation of errors (it involves RSS)
- Standard error of residual = standard deviation of the residual (it involves the hat function)

From the names, I would have thought they mean the same thing, but clearly they are not the same.
To increase confusion, the standardized residual is defined by

- dividing with the "Residual standard error" (in John Neter -"Applied linear regression models" page 110 equation 4.5)
- dividing with the "Standard error of residual" (in SAS documentation).

Question: can you clarify the two terms and the correct formula for the standardized residual. Thank you.